# Windows Server 180 days evaluation period for individuals

Tags: windows-server-2016

Can i as individual get access to 180 evaluation period for windows server. Problem is it says it requires name of a company and company phone number

Comment: not realy since its about a specific thing and specific situation

Comment: Yes, really. Just put your own name and number in, but licensing questions are still off-topic here even with specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to download [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016) ISO file from Microsoft.

While you can provide a legitimate company name (because most home users won't use this), you can also just fill something in. It doesn't matter that much.

Bonus tip:
If you want to extend your trial, you can run the command

> slmgr -rearm

to extend it for 120 days. See [this](https://sid-500.com/2017/08/08/windows-server-2016-evaluation-how-to-extend-the-trial-period/) how-to for more info.